# how to move div to left on every click - just javascript no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, move, slide

I am trying to build a slide show from scratch. I want to use only javascript, no jquery.

As of now, when I click on the 'prev' button, it only moves 50px to left just once. How do I make it move 50px every time on click of 'prev' button.

Javascript Code :-

```
function prev() {
    document.getElementById('slide').style.left = document.getElementById('slide').style.left - 50;
}

function nxt() {
    document.getElementById('slide').style.left = document.getElementById('slide').style.left + 50;
}
```

HTML :-

```
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
    <h1>Slide Show</h1>
    <div class="slideshow-outside-container">
        <div class="slideshow-inner-container" id="slide">
            <ul>
                <li class="slide slide1"></li>
                <li class="slide slide2"></li>
                <li class="slide slide3"></li>
                <li class="slide slide4"></li>
                <li class="slide slide5"></li>

                <li class="slide slide1"></li>
                <li class="slide slide2"></li>
                <li class="slide slide3"></li>
                <li class="slide slide4"></li>
                <li class="slide slide5"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow-controls-wrapper">
        <button onclick="prev()" class="prev">Prev</button>
        <button onclick="nxt()" class="nxt">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
body{
font-family: 'tahoma', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #999999;
background-color: #cccccc;
}

ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
padding: 0;
display: block;
}

.slideshow-wrapper{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.slideshow-outside-container h1{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.slideshow-outside-container{
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
width: 80%;
height: 150px;
background-color: #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow-inner-container{
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
left: 0;
width: 1920px;
height: 140px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.slide{
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 140px;
margin-right: 20px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.slide1{
background-color: green;
}

.slide2{
background-color: yellow;
}

.slide3{
background-color: red;
}

.slide4{
background-color: blue;
}

.slide5{
background-color: orange;
}

.slideshow-controls-wrapper button{
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is: you're moving the complete container `#slide` and also you have pairs of `.slide1 .slide1` what kind of gallery is that?

Comment: :-) well at the moment I not worried abt the perfect gallery - just want to learn javascript and how things are done step by step. Sorry for the incorrect logic

Comment: can you provide your css as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that the `slide` element does not have a current value for left, so even parsing it will return `NaN` and not work. You can `parseInt` the current value (`50px` parses to `50`), but default it to `0` using `||`, then +/- 50.

When you set the value you also need to say which units it is in, in your case 'px'.

You could cache the value in a variable as some people have suggested, but I don't really see the need. Parsing it each time is quick enough, ensures the function does what it is meant to each time and you don't run the risk of the stored value getting out of sync.

```
function prev() {
    var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slide').style.left, 10) || 0) - 50;
    document.getElementById('slide').style.left = val + 'px';
}

function nxt() {
    var val = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slide').style.left, 10) || 0) + 50;
    document.getElementById('slide').style.left = val + 'px';
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4c0er2s2/)

Comment: this works - and thanks for the explanation - I needed something of this sort to move forward

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function prev(){
var val=parseint(document.getElementById('slide').style.left) - 50;
document.getElementById('slide').style.left =  val+"px";
}
```

**EDIT**

This answer have some limitation..

Comment: Give also a suggestion to cache elements, also it's camelCase `parseInt` and you're missign the `radix` parameter

Comment: in this case you may just cache the `style` object.

Comment: this gives an error in console - Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: @StacyJ the `slide` id is obviously declared in your HTML, so no reason it could be null. This code should work BTW.

Comment: @KingKing - sorry I had edited the HTML - the id was missing - now no error - but div not moving left

Comment: @StacyJ yes, that msg means the `getElementById` returns null, which consequently means the id `slide` does not exist. How could it be so? I see it's declared in your HTML code. Also be sure your HTML DOM ***has been loaded*** before you run the code. I guess you were just eager to test it and call the function right away such as in `<head>` section ...